# Import OpenVINO from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, openvino

My setup is the following:

- macOS Big Sur
- pyenv
- PyCharm + venv
- Python 3.7.7
- OpenVINO 2021.1.110

I am trying to import OpenVINO:

```
import openvino
from openvino import inference_engine
```

This results in the following error when running in PyCharm (i.e. PyCharm configuration that is when using the *Play* button):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/code/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openvino import inference_engine
  File "/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openvino/inference_engine/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ie_api import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openvino/inference_engine/ie_api.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libinference_engine.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openvino/inference_engine/ie_api.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

If I run the same file from the PyCharm terminal it works just fine:

```
python3 test.py
```

How can I have it working with PyCharm? I would need to debug some code.

Comment: It seems like some dependences of OpenVINO weren't  installed properly, but the code does work when invoked from a terminal. So I'm guessing the dependences were installed in the folder from which you're calling your script. Also, maybe try to delete and reinstall OpenVINO.

Comment: No, I am calling the script from within the PyCharm's terminal. OpenVINO has been installed with a GUI installer. I tried to install it again but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that every OpenVINO toolkit usage requires the initialization of setupvars.sh.

You can set it permanently or if not, you need to initialize it each time you open a new terminal.

Make sure that the initialization message appears when you init it. It should appear automatically each time you open a new terminal if you had set it permanently.

Just to be sure, make sure that you had everything done according to this [guide](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_get_started_get_started_macos.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that you have initialised OpenVINO environment in the terminal. Maybe you have s`ource intel/openvino_2021/bin/setupvars.sh` in your `.profile` file.
The script `bin/setupvars.sh` inside the OpenVINO package set up environment variables (first of all `PYTHONPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) to the OpenVINO binaries.
So you need to cope the values of this variables from the terminal and past this variables with the value to your configuration in PyCharm